# Firebase v9 and Nuxt 2.15.8 - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, netlify

I'm migrating my codebase to use the firebase version 9 SDK and started to get this error once I started using v9 firestore. I've already migrated the auth part of my and that works perfectly.

I should note, this only happens when I'm statically generating my website (`npm run generate`) but not when building the site for SSR (`npm run build`). During development (`npm run dev`) I get no errors. The error turns up for every page that has to be generated. It seems to be referencing the `messaging` module but I'm not using `messaging` on every page. See an example of the error below:

```
 ERROR   /faqs

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
  plugins: [
    {src: '@/plugins/firebase',ssr: true },
  ]
```

`plugins/firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/storage'
import 'firebase/compat/messaging'
import 'firebase/compat/functions'


/*********************************** VERSION NINE ********************************** */
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: ''
};

let firebaseApp;

const apps = getApps();
if (!apps.length) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebaseApp = apps[0];
}

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp, {});
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

if(process.browser){
  const analytics = getAnalytics(); //enable analytics
}
/*********************************** END OF VERSION NINE ********************************** */


/*********************************** VERSION EIGHT ********************************** */
if(!firebase.apps.length){
    const config = {
        apiKey: '',
        authDomain: '',
        databaseURL: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        appId: '',
        measurementId: ''
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    
}


const fireDb = firebase.firestore();
const fireStorage =firebase.storage();
const fireFunctions =firebase.functions();

let fireMessage = '';
if(process.browser){

  if(firebase.messaging.isSupported()){
   
    fireMessage= firebase.messaging();
  }
  else{
      
    console.warn('[WARNING] Firebase Cloud messaging not supported');
  }

}
/*********************************** END OF VERSION EIGHT ********************************** */

export{fireMessage, fireDb, fireStorage, fireFunctions, auth, db}
```

I'd really appreciate some guidance on this matter. There was a [tutorial](https://lupas.medium.com/firebase-9-beta-nuxt-js-981cf3dac910) I was following, the code is at [this link](https://github.com/lupas/firebase-beta-9-nuxt). I cloned that project and ran `npm run generate` successfully so I don't think the error is with firebase? I've appended what was left of the build log below (it was really long so the terminal doesn't have the full log):

```
i Full static generation activated
i Generating output directory: dist/
i Generating pages with full static mode

 ERROR   /about

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /faqs

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /legislation

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /references

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /vaccinationsites

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/addevent

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/addinitiative

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/addsite

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/dashboard

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/deploy

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/login

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/notifications

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/sitelocations

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /admin/updatestatistics

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)


 ERROR   /

C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\index.sw.esm2017.js:1
import '@firebase/installations';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\@firebase\messaging-compat\dist\index.cjs.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\covid19-tt\node_modules\firebase\compat\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:3:1)

√ Client-side fallback created: 200.html
√ Static manifest generated
i Generating sitemaps
√ Generated /sitemap.xml
√ Generated /sitemap.xml.gz
```

Comment: Can you add `"type": "module"` to your package.json and see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: @Prabir thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: While following the tutorial you have shared, in which step you are getting the error?

Comment: @Prabir at the very end, running the command ```npm run generate``` to build the static version of the site. The SSR version ```npm run build``` runs completely fine

Comment: In the firebase.js file under Version Nine you are not using compat as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat). If that does not help can you try changing the import statements to require statements and see if that works?

Comment: @Prabir I'm using both the compat version and v9 at the same time since the codebase is in migration. The necessary imports are at the top of ```firebase.js```. I'll try the require statements and get back to you

Comment: Did you try with require statements?

Comment: @Prabir I think it's an error on Firebase's end. I filed an issue on their github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5854

Comment: Great. It seems the issue has been resolved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue on Firebase's end with the way they bundled the package and the way Nuxt does static generation.

You can read more about it here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5854.

The issue was resolved by upgrading to v9.6.3 of the Firebase JS SDK

Answer (score 1):

For me importing firebase, I used the import method to bypass the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error. For example:

```
import("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js").then(
(firebase) => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
    };
    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    //...
});
```

Of course in your case you would firebase/app instead of the remote js, but it is always another option.

Comment: Thanks! Would this still give you all the treeshaking benefits?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can pick and chose the modules to import like the import {} from "____", but you can check this out: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-import/